# Finding peaks of curve with small values

Tags: peak-detection

I have 2d data of which I want to find the peaks.

```
data << "http://pastebin.com/raw/EQFz1KFn";
peaks = FindPeaks[data[[All, 2]], 0, 0, -Infinity] // N
```

The magnitudes of the found peaks are wrong:

```
{{22., 2.58437*10^-10}, {67., 2.86902*10^-10}, 
{109., 2.98093*10^-10}, {150., 3.21527*10^-10}, 
{189.5, 3.10375*10^-10}}

ListPlot[
 data[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[peaks]}, ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

If I multiply the numbers e.g. with `10^10` then the peaks are found correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are often problems with interpolating functions when the dependent and independent variables have such widely different ranges.  The problem goes away if you rescale your values before finding the peaks,

```
data = << "http://pastebin.com/raw/EQFz1KFn";
peaks = {#1, 10^-10 #2} & @@@ 
  FindPeaks[10^10 data[[All, 2]], 0, 0, -Infinity, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1]
(* {{23, 5.13993*10^-10}, {68, 3.99016*10^-10}, {110, 
  3.43787*10^-10}, {150, 3.50107*10^-10}, {190, 3.5024*10^-10}} *)

ListPlot[data[[All, 2]], 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[peaks]}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

We can check what value of the rescaling is needed in order for the peaks to be found with `Manipulate`,

```
Manipulate[
 sf = 10^sff;
 peaks = FindPeaks[ sf data[[All, 2]], 0, 0, -Infinity, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 1];
 ListPlot[data[[All, 2]]/mx, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{#1, #2/mx/sf} & @@@ peaks]},
   ImageSize -> Large]
 , {{sff, 0}, 0, 2, .01}]
```

[image]

The fact that the largest peaks are found first indicates that there is some absolute threshold value of the peak-valley that must be reached, not a relative threshold.

What is that threshold value?  To check I'll do a peak fitting on a single cycle of a cosine curve, and take the percent difference between the actual peak value and the peak value found by `FindPeaks`, and plot it using a logarithmic x-axis.

```
scalingpeaklist = Table[
   sf = 10^-n;
   list = Table[sf (-Cos[x] + 1), {x, 0, 2 \[Pi] + 0, .01}];
   {n, (Max[list] - #2)/
      Max[list] & @@ (First@FindPeaks[list, 0, 0, -Infinity])},
   {n, 0, 14, .1}];

ListLinePlot@scalingpeaklist
```

[image]

Around $10^{-8}$.  If the difference between peaks and valleys is smaller than that, then the peak found is about half it's actual size (relative to the nearest valley).

If your peaks are going to be smaller than that, you are better off always rescaling before and after peak finding.

Comment: Beaten by 1 min, nice educational use of rescale, +1

Comment: How do I know when I have to rescale?

Comment: @mrz, you don't have to mark it as solved, I clearly didn't read the question fully and I feel like a dunce lol, was going to delete it when you mentioned it (in a deleted comment?)

Comment: But you get now the right amplitudes ... when is it necessary to rescale?

Comment: @mrz, see the edit

Comment: Brute force: `ListPlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize@10, Red, 
   Point@data[[First /@ FindPeaks@Standardize[Last /@ data]]]}]`

Comment: The threshold investigation is very interesting ... thanks for the details.

Comment: @Kuba: wau ... I did not know this function `Standardize`.

Comment: "How do I know when I have to rescale?" - any time you have to deal with widely varying magnitudes, a good choice of units (i.e. rescaling) such that the magnitudes become comparable is paramount.